# Batch download photos from Yahoo Groups

Tags: bulk-download, yahoo-groups

I want to download a complete album from a Yahoo Groups group but can't find a way to do it on the webpage except of course to click each photos thumbnail one by one and download the full image from the following page.

Is there a service or a download tool that could do this for me?

I tried to use the [DownThemAll! AntiContainer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall-anticontainer/) Firefox extension but without luck.

Comment: What is the Yahoo Group? is it public?

Comment: It is a restricted group. http://groups.yahoo.com/group/matekfizikAsok/photos/album/0/list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself but this SourceForge Project [GrabYahooGroup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/grabyahoogroup/) looks promising.

It is a command line utility that claims to download:

- all the messages from a group in the order in which they were received
- all the attachments associated with the messages
- all the content from the Files section in a group maintaining the heirarchy as present on the website
- all the content from the Photos section in a group maintaining the heirarchy as present on the website
- the members, moderators, pending and bouncing members list

Comment: This tool might work but I couldn't get it to run though. It requires Perl that you have to install separately under Windows. After I have set it all up it gave me an error message "Couldn't get message count". I tried the latest version from SVN but without luck. I think I will have to download the photos by hand.